# Error install nginx version 1.6.2 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, linux, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

My server is Ubuntu 14.04
the info.php is blank :(
I do not really know what's happening I want to install the latest version of nginx

I followed these steps:

#### install nginx

```
apt-get install python-software-properties'

add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable

apt-get update

apt-get install nginx
```

#### install php

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysql

sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

#### uncommenting line

cgi.fix_pathinfo=0

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart 

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

#### edit file

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}


sudo service nginx restart
```

create file and save

```
sudo nano /usr/share/nginx/html/info.php

<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Please help install the latest version of nginx.

Comment: I dont see any problem there, you install NGINX and nginx is working, but you install PHP ? so.. apt-get php5-fpm php5-cgi and what is the error ? you say in title error on nginx, but your problem is phinfo()... ( is phpinfo function enable on php.ini ? ), and check nginx error_log :)

Comment: My error log

     - - [21/Sep/2014:17:14:16 -0400] "GET /inhfo.php HTTP/1.1" 404 200 "-                                  " "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ch                                  rome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Since this is our first time using apt For This session, we start off by updating Should our Local package index. We can then install the server: nginx 1.4 works normally

Comment: That's your access log and you made a typo in your browser: `inhfo.php` is not `info.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solucionado!!

add code linea

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Any explanation why it is changed? I was using absolute path basing on $host and hosts folder before nginx 1.6 pulled in